# Put TextAreaField (for specifications) in a RadioField with Flask WTF

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to build a simple webform with flask and flask-wtf.

In my form I ask for the type of segmentation wanted (option: Generic, Auto and Custom). If the type is custom, I need to get a special field with the specifications.

Below is my code. It is working, but I have find it uneasy to read.

in forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, RadioField, BooleanField, TextAreaField
from wtforms import validators

class requestSettings(Form):
    typeOfSegmentation = RadioField('typeOfSegment',
                                choices=[('generic', 'by generic persona'), \
                                         ('auto', 'by automatic clustering'),
                                         ('custom', 'by manual definition')
                                         ],
                                default='generic',
                                validators=[validators.DataRequired("indicate the method to segment users")])

    typeOfSegmentation_custom = TextAreaField('custom definition')

   def validate(self):
       is_validated = True
       rv = Form.validate(self)
       if not rv:
           is_validated = False

       if self.typeOfSegmentation.data == 'custom':
            if not self.typeOfSegmentation_custom.data:
                 self.typeOfSegmentation_custom.errors.append("Please specify the way you define your segments")
                 is_validated = False

       return is_validated
```

in my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Your request is {{ session_id }} <br>

{% for field, errors in form.errors.items() %}
    {% for error in errors %}
        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}<br>
{% block content %}
        <h1>Segmentation</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" name="name">
        <p>Select the method to segment user:
        <table>
        <tr>
        {% for subfield in form.typeOfSegmentation %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ subfield }}</td>
            <td>{{ subfield.label }}</td>
            {% if loop.index0 == 2 %}
               <td > Enter manual description {{form.typeOfSegmentation_custom}}
               </td>
            {% endif %}

            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this the proper way to do it? Does radiobuttons + text fields exist in flask WTF?